# Magento Error After Enable the Category Flat Data

Tags: magento

I have ennabled the **Category Flat Data** in admin panel System --> index management.
After enable the **Category Flat Data**  product positions are not working in front end.
Also my product previous and next buttons are getting below error in product details page.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition() in /var/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 308
```

Right now i am using the magento ver. 1.5.1.0.

Also i have tried [this method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/240820/#t364335)

So can any one help me? how to fix this issues? can any one suggest me the solution?

Thanks

Comment: There was a issues in my collection.i have modified my collection..

Comment: this is great to hear that.. what was the issue is this something related with your customization work or general please share    
because i am complete stuck with this.

Comment: @ManKingdom, I am getting same error. Can you tell me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Reindex required for flat data collection

Please try index management